# Why does the layout for rails project get ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've attached a picture of my project which I just created. Even though the application.html.erb is present my template ignores it and the page is rendered without the surrounding html inside the layout.

I have even tried to specify the layout using the `layout` option in my controller without success.

The project was generated with --skip-active-record flag because I'm using mongodb without an ORM. I don't think this has anything to do with it. Right??

[image]

Comment: How do you see that the template is not used? Do you not see the title in the header of the browser? Is there an error in the log? By any chance have you configured sass and haml instead of erb?

Comment: Turned out it was a bad initialisation problem. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out the problem.

In my controller I had defined a new constructor which didn't call its super class like so:

```
def initialize
    @default_report_days = 30
end
```

Once the controller was correctly initialised the layout started being picked up.

```
def initialize
    super
    @default_report_days = 30
end
```